# Exporting MobileFirst Analytics data

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

I've captured some event logs from my MobileFirst 7.1 client app (hybrid for iOS) using the Analytics API:

```
WL.Analytics.log({'Module': 'Account', 'Activity': 'Update account'}, 'Message Title');
```

And I could retrieve the logs from the Analytics Console without any problem.

Next I would retrieve the logs using the [Analytics API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_raw_reports.html). Below is a working url format:

```
http://localhost:10080/analytics-service/data/administration/apps/worklight/export?query={"event":"CustomData","format":"json","limit":10,"offset":0,"startDate":"2016-08-24","endDate":"*"}
```

which returns the following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "mfpAppName": "myApp",
    "deviceOS": "ios",
    "appID": "worklight",
    "mfpAppVersion": "1.0",
    "deviceOSversion": "7",
    "deviceModel": "xxx",
    "deviceID": "xxx",
    "timestamp": "1472038253030",
    "Module": "Account",
    "Activity": "Update account"
  }
]
```

My questions:

1. How can I filter my JSON results based on my custom data? For example, I want to retrieve logs for all activities which have the value: "Module": "Account" only.
2. How can I sort the JSON results, for example, based on the timestamp value?
3. When I tried to add in my own parameter(e.g. "filter") into the url, it would return an error which says:

   {"err":"Unrecognized field \"filter\" (class com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.rest.params.ExportParameters), not marked as ignorable (29 known properties: , \"level\", \"validationCode\", \"serverIpAddress\", \"mfpAppVersion\", \"hours\", \"realm\", \"adapter\", \"debug\", \"offset\", \"mfpAppName\", \"event\", \"deviceOSversion\", \"timestampKey\", \"endDate\" [truncated]])\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4c3deb33; line: 1, column: 33] (through reference chain: com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.rest.params.ExportParameters[\"search\"])"}

   May I know where can I find all the "29 known properties" as it mentions?

I learned that the MFP Analytics is using ElasticSearch as its engine and I tried to find any info about this but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your goal you are going to have to enable the Elasticsearch REST endpoint. If you are on a Liberty server this is very simple, use the JNDI properties below.

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/http.enabled" value="true"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/httpport" value="9500"/>
```

After enabling the Elasticsearch REST endpoint you can write custom queries against the backend.

You can write a POST request similar to the one below:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9500/worklight/_search?sort=timestamp:asc' -d '{"query" : {"wildcard":{"worklight_data.Module": {"value": "Account"}}}}'
```

Some Elasticsearch references you may find useful:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-uri-request.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-request-body.html

Comment: Hi Chevy, thanks for the tip of using ElasticSearch REST endpoint. I've tested it on my local development machine and it works. However, when I tried to do the same with my remote development server (hosted at AWS) it returned a "Could not get any response" error. FYI, our remote development server is also running on a Liberty server. We've opened the port 9500 in AWS administration and restarted our MFP instance after updating the server.xml file. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I've found a link which describes the properties and configurations that can be set on the MobileFirst Server in the worklight.properties file: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_properties.html. However, the .properties file does not use the XML <tag> format. Is it correct if I change the JNDI properties above to something like: wl.analytics.httpport=9500 | wl.analytics.http.enabled=true ?

Comment: After a weeklong trial and error, found out that there's another server.xml file used by the Analytics Server and inserted the JNDI properties there. Now it is working properly from our AWS server.